# Site can't load while Mysql Queries are executing

Tags: php, mysql, apache2

I have MySQL 5.7 server on one machine.
Website is on other machine.

While I try to F5 20 times PHP mysql-script that needs 1 second to execute it will freeze whole website for everyone for 20 seconds

I tried run this on nginx, apache2 so i guess its mysql or website problem.

Query can be simple SELECT in loop, i use mysqli_query

When i checked FULL PROCESSLIST it showed me only one process of website user and it was all executing in queue untill i stopped refreshing, main problem is that other users can't load website while i execute this.

Comment: Ultimately your queries are running too slowly and you need to speed them up. Consider indexing some tables. Also if you show us the SQL statements you are executing someone may be able to be nice and suggest improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Only one PHP process can have a given session open at a time, all subsequent requests attempting to open that session will block until it is closed. Resulting in the problem you have described.

If you have everything you need from the session, and don't plan to write anything more to it, then you can call [`session_write_close()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) to free up the session for other requests.

eg:

```
<?php
session_start();

// init

session_write_close();

$dbh->query('SELECT super_long_time_stuff FROM foo');
```

**Edit:** It's worth noting that this won't cause "all users" to be unable to load pages, just any user that's locked their own session by making a long-running request.

Comment: Well, it was good idea and it fits.
It pretty much was the same with session_write_close();
I changed server for a better one and issue is i hope gone. Thanks for answer anyway.